# Can't get angular-masonry to work

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, masonry

I've installed angular-masonry and tried to use it with my single-page Bootstrap view. The images from the `ng-repeat` directive render but only in a single column. I am not able to figure out why and I am not getting any JS errors.

This is my view:

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
          <masonry column-width="230">
            <div ng-repeat="image in results.images">
                <img class="asset_image" ng-src="{{ image.url }}" alt="A masonry brick">
            </div>
          </masonry>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official Docs:
**You still need to use masonry-brick either as class name or element attribute on sub-elements in order to register it to the directive.**

Don't you need the masonry-brick class or attribute?

```
<div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="image in results.images">
    <img class="asset_image" ng-src="{{ image.url }}" alt="A masonry brick">
</div>
```

or

```
<div masonry-brick ng-repeat="image in results.images">
    <img class="asset_image" ng-src="{{ image.url }}" alt="A masonry brick">
</div>
```

Final sample:

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
          <masonry column-width="230">
            <div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="image in results.images">
                <img class="asset_image" ng-src="{{ image.url }}" alt="A masonry brick">
            </div>
          </masonry>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're right, this was definitely missing (I had this in one of my trials and then I removed it because I was trying different things and then I forgot to undo). However, it still doesn't work. Actually even this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/jvg8AZ?p=preview
doesn't work for me. I again only get one column. T

Comment: the example you provided works fine for me, I get two columns with different pictures.

Comment: I meant, the plnkr example itself works on the plnkr page but not when I copy it into my project. No console errors unfortunately...

Comment: did you check if any CSS classes override angular masonry defined ones? do you have padding on your items? How about margin?

Comment: that's tough, it just looks like the bricks are too large for the container.. what's the width of each brick?

Comment: Each brick div is 400x200

Comment: You were right, the template I was using was setting very narrow .container class. I changed it now and it worked. Thank you SO much!